# Append command to existing environment without redefining it altogether

Tags: macros, environments, verse

I'm investigating how to customize environments provided by other packages without having to redefine the env completely in my document preamble.

Specifically, the `verse` package define its environment as following and I just want to make all the lines italic (with a simple `\itshape`) without having to type it every time after like `\begin{verse}\itshape ... \end{verse}` as I'm using it very often and I'd like to integrate it once for all in the env for my document.

```
106 \renewenvironment{verse}[1][\linewidth]{%
107 \stepcounter{verse@envctr}%
108 \setcounter{poemline}{0}\refstepcounter{poemline}%
109 \setcounter{vslineno}{1}%
110 \let\\=\@vscentercr
111 \list{}{\itemsep \z@
112 \itemindent -\vindent%
113 \listparindent\itemindent
114 \parsep \stanzaskip
115 \ifdim #1 < \linewidth
116 \rightmargin \z@
117 \setlength{\leftmargin}{\linewidth}%
118 \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-#1}%
119 \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\leftmargin}%
120 \else
121 \rightmargin \leftmargin
122 \fi
123 \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\vindent}}%
124 \item[]%
125 }
126 {\endlist}
```

Comment: May be this will work for you `\usepackage{etoolbox}` `\AfterBeginEnvironment{verse}{\itshape}` or `\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\itshape}`  ( rather the second one)

Comment: My advice is to define a new environment, say `itverse`, with `\newenvironment{itverse}{\begin{verse}\itshape}{\end{verse}}`.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Hafid in the comments, I opted for the tools provided by the package `etoolbox` which implements the command `\AtBeginEnvironment{ env }{ what to append }`

Hence I implemented in my code:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\itshape}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\let` command to do the trick. Notice that`\newenvironment{verse}{}{}` has created commands `\verse` and `\endverse`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\myverse\verse % store the definition of \verse in \myverse
\renewcommand{\verse}{\myverse\itshape} % renew the definition of \verse to previous difinition plus \itshape

\begin{document}    
\begin{verse}
    \lipsum
\end{verse} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP uses the `verse` package where the verse environment takes an optional argument. Take another look at your answer when used with the `verse` package.

Comment: True, unfortunately it is not obvious (at least to me) how to overcome that problem. I believe using a different environment or the etoolbox package are better solutions.